# trying to MarshalJSON an EnrichedActivity with the golang lib

Tags: go, getstream-io

I am trying to get the correct JSON from an enriched flat stream of enrichedActivites.
The enrichedActvivites are stored correctly, I used [this doc](https://getstream.io/docs/enrichment/?language=go) to implement it.

I cannot marshal the enriched objects to json. To marshal the enrichedactivities I use the MarshalJson Method:
https://github.com/GetStream/stream-go2/blob/master/enriched_activities.go

There you can read

> MarshalJSON encodes the EnrichedActivity to a valid JSON bytes slice. It's required because of the custom JSON fields and time formats.

Unfortunately something is still wrong.

this  is my code:
1. getting the activities:

```
timelineFeed, err := streamClient.FlatFeed("timeline", this.Actor.Person.Id)
enrichedResp, err := timelineFeed.GetEnrichedActivities(opts...)

// dumping for debugging
for _, result := range enrichedResp.Results {
    fmt.Println("enriched activity:")
    spew.Dump(result)

    fmt.Println("enriched activity json:")
    b, _ := result.MarshalJSON()
    fmt.Printf("%s", b)
}
```

this is my enrichedActivity:

```
(stream.EnrichedActivity) {
 ID: (string) (len=36) "76f4a2ae-a6ba-11ea-8080-800076210678",
 Actor: (stream.Data) {
  ID: (string) (len=2) "12",
  Extra: (map[string]interface {}) (len=3) {
   (string) (len=10) "updated_at": (string) (len=27) "2020-05-27T21:29:25.479602Z",
   (string) (len=10) "created_at": (string) (len=27) "2020-05-25T16:24:05.467916Z",
   (string) (len=4) "data": (map[string]interface {}) (len=4) {
    (string) (len=8) "username": (string) (len=35) "usernam@website",
    (string) (len=7) "website": (string) (len=11) "web.site",
    (string) (len=4) "name": (string) (len=16) "user name",
    (string) (len=9) "photo_url": (string) (len=79) "http://auth.blorm/storage/profiles/GoKZpG9uCru1LC020rwBbAuD1hV9u5GN9A6jMoY4.png"
   }
  }
 },
 Verb: (string) (len=6) "create",
 Object: (stream.Data) {
  ID: (string) (len=52) "web-site-a-uinque-headline-for-hello-world",
  Extra: (map[string]interface {}) (len=5) {
   (string) (len=4) "data": (map[string]interface {}) (len=4) {
    (string) (len=8) "Headline": (string) (len=8) "headline",
    (string) (len=5) "Image": (string) (len=3) "non",
    (string) (len=4) "Text": (string) (len=18) "teasertext",
    (string) (len=3) "Url": (string) (len=60) "http://web.site/a-uinque-headline-for-hello-world/"
   },
   (string) (len=10) "foreign_id": (string) (len=59) "teaser:web-site-a-uinque-headline-for-hello-world",
   (string) (len=10) "updated_at": (string) (len=26) "2020-06-04T21:23:57.78888Z",
   (string) (len=10) "collection": (string) (len=6) "teaser",
   (string) (len=10) "created_at": (string) (len=26) "2020-06-04T21:23:57.78888Z"
  }
 },
 ForeignID: (string) "",
 Target: (stream.Data) {
  ID: (string) (len=7) "user:12",
  Extra: (map[string]interface {}) <nil>
 },
 Time: (stream.Time) 2020-06-04 23:23:57.809323 +0000 UTC,
 Origin: (stream.Data) {
  ID: (string) "",
  Extra: (map[string]interface {}) <nil>
 },
 To: ([]string) <nil>,
 Score: (float64) 0,
 ReactionCounts: (map[string]int) {
 },
 OwnReactions: (map[string][]*stream.EnrichedReaction) <nil>,
 LatestReactions: (map[string][]*stream.EnrichedReaction) {
 },
 Extra: (map[string]interface {}) (len=3) {
  (string) (len=8) "category": ([]interface {}) {
  },
  (string) (len=22) "latest_reactions_extra": (map[string]interface {}) {
  },
  (string) (len=7) "summary": (string) (len=33) "user name created a Teaser"
 }
}
```

this is a dump of the map which generates the MarhsalJSON method for internal use

```
(map[string]interface {}) (len=8) {
 (string) (len=6) "target": (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=2) "id": (string) (len=7) "user:12"
 },
 (string) (len=4) "time": (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=4) "Time": (time.Time) 2020-06-04 23:23:57.809323 +0000 UTC
 },
 (string) (len=15) "reaction_counts": (map[string]int) {
 },
 (string) (len=16) "latest_reactions": (map[string][]*stream.EnrichedReaction) {
 },
 (string) (len=2) "id": (string) (len=36) "76f4a2ae-a6ba-11ea-8080-800076210678",
 (string) (len=5) "actor": (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=2) "id": (string) (len=2) "12"
 },
 (string) (len=4) "verb": (string) (len=6) "create",
 (string) (len=6) "object": (map[string]interface {}) (len=1) {
  (string) (len=2) "id": (string) (len=52) "blog1-blorm-und-noch-eine-headline-fuer-ahllo-welt-2"
 }
}
```

and this is the json which is generated

```
{"actor":{"id":"12"},"category":[],"id":"76f4a2ae-a6ba-11ea-8080-800076210678","latest_reactions":{},"latest_reactions_extra":{},"object":{"id":"blog1-blorm-und-noch-eine-headline-fuer-ahllo-welt-2"},"reaction_counts":{},"summary":"Florian Kuhlmann created a Teaser","target":{"id":"user:12"},"time":"2020-06-04T23:23:57.809323","verb":"create"}
```

As far as I can see the json correspnds to the map which is genereated by MarshallJson for internal use. but the map also misses the enriched object and the enriched actor.

What did I do wrong? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The json seems to match the dump so I'm not sure this has anything to do with json and the standard go lib. Isn't the problem the fact that `GetEnrichedActivities` does not return what you expect it to return? Can you clarify what the actual problem is and maybe remove stuff from the question that is irrelevant?

Comment: right. the json matches the dump. 
the problem is, that the generated map AND the json does not correspond to the enrichedActivity. 
its not about the standard go lib. its about the specific method i linked in the post.

Comment: First off, in case you're not aware, the `\`json:"-"\`` tag explicitly indicates to the `encoding/json` package that it should ignore the tagged field. Second, the objects you're missing are [these](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-go2/blob/7b1805d008c42e2552277e96d37765a813b44466/types.go#L84). While the `EnrichedActivity` type, with its `Un/MarshalJSON` methods does make effort to include its own [`Extra`](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-go2/blob/master/enriched_activities.go#L25) field, the `Data` type, on the other hand, does not, ....

Comment: ... it does not implement the json (un)marshaler interfaces and will therefore be marshaled as is, i.e. the `Data.Extra` field *will* be ignored because of the `-` in the json tag, so, to answer your "What did I do wrong" question: Nothing, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: dear mkopriva, thanx for your patience. yes this is what i found out too. 
i am just wondering what the whole concept for rendering the enrichedActivity is, since the Object and the Actor (stream.Data) is a feature of the library. 
i do not understand why the correct rendering of theses objects as json is not implemented in the lib.
feature or bug? :-)

Comment: It's by design. Types in SDK are types for reading from server response, they don't implement marshaler. If you want to do more, you need to get the data into your type and do your custom rendering.

Comment: thanx to all. even if i dont have a solution now, at least i know i have to figure out my own way to handle it. :-)